# Why does asynchronous writeFile method behave synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have a simple JS file that reads a text file and the writes it and reads the changed file. For learning purposes, I have implemented the below code.

When the control reaches `writeFile`, shouldn't it be running in the background and the control should go to the `console.log("Test")` line and then back to the `writeFile`? But it actually fully executes the writeFile and control goes to the log line which is basically a synchronous behavior. Am I missing something here ?

```js
console.log("Begin")
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("input.txt", function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Inside Read " + data.toString());
    fs.writeFile("input.txt", "Replaced Text", function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Inside Write");
        var data = fs.readFileSync("Input.txt") console.log(data + " is the replaced text");
      }
      console.log("Test2");
    });
  }
});
console.log("Ended");
```

Comment: `console.log("Test2")` is inside `writeFile` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log("Test2")` is inside of the `writeFile` callback function and will not run until `writeFile` is completed.

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("input.txt", function(err, data) {
  console.log("This will second, after print after readFile is complete);
  fs.writeFile("input.txt", "Replaced Text", function(err) {
    console.log("This will print last, after writeFile is complete");
  });
  console.log("This will print third, before writeFile is complete");
});
console.log("This will print first");
```